# Shifting elements and printing each step

Tags: java, arrays, random

Im trying to shift elements in an array and print each step until they are back to their original positions. The array has to be filled with random numbers and must not be over the size of 15. I approached the task by creating a new array when the shifting occurs. If anyone has any better suggestions let me know.
Ive done the array and the shifting part once, but cant seem to figure out how to repeat it.
Here is what I came up with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Enter size: ");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int p = s.nextInt();
    if (p > 15) {
        System.out.println("Too much to handle!");
    }
    int oldArray[] = new int [p];
for (int i = 0; i<oldArray.length;i++) {
        oldArray[i]=(int)(Math.random()*10);
    }
    int newArray[] = moveA(oldArray);
    printA(oldArray);
    printA(newArray);
}

public static int[] moveA(int[] array1) {
int[] array2 = new int[array1.length];

 for (int i = 0; i < array2.length - 1; i++) {
    array2[i+1] = array1[i];
}
array2[0] = array1[array1.length - 1];
return array2;
}

public static void printA(int[] arr) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
```

The code prints like this:

```
Enter size: 
4
[1, 5, 9, 3]
[3, 1, 5, 9]
```

Ive tried doing a for loop at:

```
for ( int b = 0; b <= oldArray.length; b++)
int newArray[] = moveA(oldArray);
printA(oldArray);
printA(newArray)
```

but all it does is print it 4 times.

Comment: Welcome to SO. The problem with your code is that your assigning the rotated array to a new variable inside the loop. Because `oldArray` never changes it gets the same value every iteration. See my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of times you shift will be the same as the size of the array. So you really just need a `for` loop:

```
int[] original = ...;
int[] current = original;
for (int i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    current = moveA(current);
    printA(current);
}
```

The random numbers might happen to generate an array with a replicated sequence that returns to the original position before a full cycle is complete. If you need to allow for that situation:

```
int[] current = moveA(original);
while (!Array.equals(current, orginal)) {
    printA(current);
    current = moveA(current);
}
```

Finally, Java 8+ gives you a faster way of generating an array of random numbers. The following will generate an array of 5 ints in the range 0-9:

```
int[] original = new Random().ints(5, 0, 10).toArray();
```

Comment: It works. Thanks for the tip on how to create the array easier. At first it replicated the original and printed it out N number of times but i managed to get around it with a slightly different for loop since the while loop didnt work. (equals didnt work)